# Upload a file tool in HTML

Tags: html, web, upload, uploading

I have a static HTML website, in this website I have 2 pages for downloading PDFs and I upload and put files in the website in daily basis but I am doing it a hard way which I open a server (FTP) every time and re-edit the code to add a new item in (Downloads page) with links and name and staff.

What I want to know and have is a tool of a page in my website which I can reach it securely and upload my files by one-click without opening domain FTP each time,

But the important thing I want is when every time I upload a file it will automatically add new item in (Downloads) and become easy to download.
I REALLY NEED YOUR HELP

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do what your asking with a static site alone. For file uploads via a page on your site you will, at the very least need some sort of back end language to store the file in the server's file system for you.

While there are some tools like Jekyll our there that may assist with updating static pages, it really sounds like you need a content management system (CMS).

Drupal and Wordpress are two of the most popular ones out there, personally I have only ever used Wordpress.

Wordpress, like any other CMS worth its salt, offers a admin dashboard in a secure and private section of your website where you can modify, create and delete content + much more.

[image]
https://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Screen

There are heaps of premade themes for Wordpress out there or you can create a new one based off your static site. And again there is heaps of information

Comment: @Reber does this answer your question or do you need more information?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am busy nowadays when I use the mentioned above I will tell you and ask you. Thanks again god bless you